# How do I pull data from a server, make it easy to access, and make it persistent without slowing down the interface of my application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

While building my app, Marco Polo (getmarcopolo.com), I found that one of the most challenging parts of the app was pulling data from the server without slowing down the interface and without it crashing. I've got it settled now, and wanted to share my knowledge with any other developers having the same issue.

When pulling data from a server, there are a number of factors that need to be taken into consideration:

1. Data integrity - No data is ever missed from the server
2. Data persistence - Data is cached and can be accessed even when offline
3. Lack of interference with the interface (main thread) - Achieved using multithreading
4. Speed - Achieved using thread concurrency
5. Lack of thread collisions - Achieved using serial thread queues

So the question is, how do you achieve all 5?

I've answered this below, but would love to hear feedback on how to improve the process (with this example), as I feel it is not very easy to find in one place right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be using the example of refreshing the marco's in the notification feed. I'll also be referring to Apple's GCD library (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). First, we create a singleton (see http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/):

```
@implementation MPOMarcoPoloManager

+ (MPOMarcoPoloManager *)instance {

    static MPOMarcoPoloManager *_instance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            _instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _instance;
}

@end
```

This allows for us to call [MPOMarcoPoloManager instance] at any time, from any file, and access the properties in the the singleton. It also ensures that there is always only one instance of the marco polos. 'static dispatch_once_t onceToken; dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{' ensures thread stability.

The next step is to add the data structure we will be accessing publicly. In this case, add an NSArray for the marcos to the header file, as well as a public declaration of 'instance':

```
@interface MPOMarcoPoloManager : NSObject

+ (MPOMarcoPoloManager *)instance;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *marcoPolos;

@end
```

Now that the array and the instance are accessible publicly, it's time to ensure data persistence. We will achieve this by adding the ability to cache the data. The following code will 
1. Initializes our serverQueue to the global queue, which allows multiple threads to run concurrently
2. Initializes our localQueue to a serial queue, which allows only one thread to be run at a time. All local data manipulation should be done on this thread to ensure no thread collisions
3. Gives us a method to call for caching our NSArray, with objects that conform to NSCoding (see http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)
4. Attempts to pull the data structure from the cache, and initializes a new one if it cannot

```
@interface MPOMarcoPoloManager()

@property dispatch_queue_t serverQueue;
@property dispatch_queue_t localQueue;

@end

@implementation MPOMarcoPoloManager

+ (MPOMarcoPoloManager *)instance {

    static MPOMarcoPoloManager *_instance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            _instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _instance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        _marcoPolos = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:self.marcoPolosArchivePath];

        if(!self.marcoPolos) {
            _marcoPolos = [NSArray array];
        }

        //serial queue
        _localQueue = dispatch_queue_create([[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier].UTF8String, NULL);

        //Parallel queue
        _serverQueue = dispatch_queue_create(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), NULL);
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)marcoPolosArchivePath {
    NSArray *cacheDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *cacheDirectory = [cacheDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    return [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"marcoPolos.archive"];
}

- (BOOL)saveChanges {
    BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.marcoPolos toFile:[self marcoPolosArchivePath]];
    return success;
}

@end
```

Now that we have the structure of the singleton, It's time to add the ability to refresh our marco's. Add the declarations of refreshMarcoPolosInBackgroundWithCallback:((^)(NSArray *result, NSError *error)) to the header file:

```
...
- (void)refreshMarcoPolosInBackground:((^)(NSArray *result, NSError *error))callback;
...
```

Now it's time to implement the refresh. Notice that all server calls are performed on the serverQueue (which is parallel), and any data manipulation is done on the localQueue (which is serial). When the method is completed, we use what is called a C block (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) to callback the result to the main thread. Any task that acts on a background thread should have a callback to the main thread to inform the interface that the refresh has completed (whether it be successful or not).

```
...
- (void)refreshMarcoPolosInBackground:((^)(NSArray *result, NSError *error))callback {

//error checking ommitted

    //Run the server call on the global parallel queue
    dispatch_async(_serverQueue, ^{

        NSArray *objects = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;

        //This can be any method with the declaration "- (NSArray *)fetchMarcoPolo:(NSError **)callbackError" that connects to a server and returns objects
        objects = [self fetchMarcoPolo:&error];

        //If something goes wrong, callback the error on the main thread and stop
        if(error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(nil, error);
            });
            return;
        }

        //Since the server call was successful, manipulate the data on the serial queue to ensure no thread collisions
        dispatch_async(_localQueue, ^{

            //Create a mutable copy of our public array to manipulate
            NSMutableArray *mutableMarcoPolos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_marcoPolos];

            //PFObject is a class from Parse.com
            for(PFObject *parseMarcoPoloObject in objects) {

                BOOL shouldAdd = YES;

                MPOMarcoPolo *marcoPolo = [[MPOMarcoPolo alloc] initWithParseMarcoPolo:parseMarcoPoloObject];
                for(int i = 0; i < _marcoPolos.count; i++) {
                    MPOMarcoPolo *localMP = _marcoPolos[i];
                    if([marcoPolo.objectId isEqualToString:localMP.objectId]) {

                        //Only update the local model if the object pulled from the server was updated more recently than the local object
                        if((localMP.updatedAt && [marcoPolo.updatedAt timeIntervalSinceDate:localMP.updatedAt] > 0)||
                           (!localMP.updatedAt)) {
                            mutableMarcoPolos[i] = marcoPolo;
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"THERE'S NO NEED TO UPDATE THIS MARCO POLO");
                        }
                        shouldAdd = NO;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(shouldAdd) {
                    [mutableMarcoPolos addObject:marcoPolo];
                }
            } 

            //Perform any sorting on mutableMarcoPolos if needed

            //Assign an immutable copy of mutableMarcoPolos to the public data structure
            _marcoPolos = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableMarcoPolos];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(marcoPolos, nil);
            });

        });

    });

}

...
```

You may be wondering why we would manipulate the data on a queue for something like this, but lets add a method where we can mark the marco as viewed. We don't want to have to wait for the server to update, but we also don't want to manipulate the local object in a manor that can cause a thread collision. So let's add this declaration to the header file:

```
...
- (void)setMarcoPoloAsViewed:(MPOMarcoPolo *)marcoPolo inBackgroundWithlocalCallback:((^)())localCallback
              serverCallback:((^)(NSError *error))serverCallback;
...
```

Now it's time to implement the method. Notice that the local manipulation is done on the serial queue, then immediately calls back to the main thread, allowing the interface to update without waiting for a server connection. It then updates the server, and calls back to the main thread on a separate callback to inform the interface that the server save was completed.

```
- (void)setMarcoPoloAsViewed:(MPOMarcoPolo *)marcoPolo inBackgroundWithlocalCallback:(MPOOrderedSetCallback)localCallback
              serverCallback:(MPOErrorCallback)serverCallback {

//error checking ommitted

    dispatch_async(_localQueue, ^{

        //error checking ommitted

        //Update local marcoPolo object
        for(MPOMarcoPolo *mp in self.marcoPolos) {
            if([mp.objectId isEqualToString:marcoPolo.objectId]) {

                mp.updatedAt = [NSDate date];
                //MPOMarcoPolo objcts have an array viewedUsers that contains all users that have viewed this marco. I use parse, so I'm going to add a MPOUser object that is created from [PFUser currentUser] but this can be any sort of local model manipulation you need
                [mp.viewedUsers addObject:[[MPOUser alloc] initWithParseUser:[PFUser currentUser]]];

                //callback on the localCallback, so that the interface can update
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
                    //code to be executed on the main thread when background task is finished
                    localCallback(self.marcoPolos, nil);
                });

                break;
            }
        }

    });

    //Update the server on the global parallel queue
    dispatch_async(_serverQueue, ^{

        NSError *error = nil;
        PFObject *marcoPoloParseObject = [marcoPolo parsePointer];
        [marcoPoloParseObject addUniqueObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"viewedUsers"];

        //Update marcoPolo object on server
        [marcoPoloParseObject save:&error];
        if(!error) {

            //Marco Polo has been marked as viewed on server. Inform the interface
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                serverCallback(nil);
            });

        } else {

            //This is a Parse feature that your server's API may not support. If it does not, just callback the error.
            [marcoPoloParseObject saveEventually];

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                serverCallback(error);
            });
        }

    });
}
```

With this setup, a refresh can be occuring the background, while setting a marco as viewed at the same time, while ensuring that the local model is not manipulated at the same time. While the necessity of the localQueue may not be obvious with only two methods, when having many different types of manipulation available, it becomes critical.

Answer (score 0):

I use a dataManager that contains two sub managers, core data fetch manager and restkit manager, which maps to core data.

for example:

anywhereInApp.m

```
[dataManager getData: someSearchPrecate withCompletionBlock: someBlock];
```

dataManager.m

```
- (void) getData: somePredicate withCompletionBlock: someblock{
      [self.coreDataManager fetchData: somePredicate withCompletionBlock: some block];
      [self.restkitManager fetchData: somePredicate withCompletionBlock: some block];
}
```

and then core data manger runs on a thread to fetch data and executes completion block.

and reskitmanager runs a thread and executes completion block when http request and object mapping complete.

usually the completion block updates the data shown in a collection view.

only need to worry about old data getting removed from core data, but that's another story and can involve comparing the results from the two different calls and taking appropriate action.  I try to picture a venn diagram of result sets and it all makes sense or I am too tired & drinking too good of beer.